# How to set default MdDatePicker options (translations for weekdays, months..) for all instances on one place e.g App constructor?

Tags: aurelia, materialize, pickadate

Aurelia project with TypeScript (tsc 2.1.4), JSPM and aurelia-materialize-bridge@0.20.6.

Project is multilingual (translations are in database and injected via "LanguageService" where needed) so we need translated instances of **MdDatePicker** too.

I found a way how to translate properties like *monthsFull*, *monthsShort*, *today*... per instance of MdDatePicker (pickadate.js picker's properties actually)  on this way in view/view-model:

```
    <input md-datepicker="container: body;value.two-way: fromDate;"
           md-datepicker.ref="dpickerFrom" 
           type="date" placeholder=${dtPickTitle} />

    attached(
      var picker = (<any>this).dpickerFrom.picker;    
      var settings = picker.component.settings;

      settings.monthsFull = this.languageService.datePickerTran.monthsFull; // e.g. [ 'Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember' ]
      settings.today = this.languageService.datePickerTran.today; //e.g."Heute"
      picker.render(true);
    )
```

I have tried to reach needed properties globally in App.ts:

```
import * as bridge from 'aurelia-materialize-bridge';

 constructor (){
     bridge.MdDatePicker.prototype;//Can't find where to put translations
}
```

but I could not find needed.

Is this right approach at all?
Considering given platform, is there any way to set this properties (defaults) on one place for all instances?

Comment: I've ried to give an answer here: https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/issues/133 - let's see if that helps. If so, I can post it back here. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've told the OP to post my answer back here. So here it goes.. :-)

There is an `options` bindable here: https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L19

That object is merged here: https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L64

And the result is used to initialize the datepicker here: https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L76

Now, if you visited the links you may have seen a commented example of an i18n config here (German strings): https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L47-L60

So, if you set the i18n properties in the `options` bindable, it could work..

```
<input
  md-datepicker="container: body; value.two-way: selectedDate; options.bind:i18nOptions;"
  type="date" placeholder="pick a date"/>
```

Where `i18nOptions` might be:

```
{
   selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
   selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
   monthsFull: [ 'Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember' ],
   monthsShort: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez' ],
   weekdaysFull: [ 'Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag' ],
   weekdaysShort: [ 'So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa' ],
   today: 'Heute',
   clear: 'Löschen',
   close: 'Schließen',
   firstDay: 1,
   format: 'dddd, dd. mmmm yyyy',
   formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
}
```

I definitely want to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar answer

In my view I have

```
<div class="input-field col s6">                        
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FECHAI_VIG, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "fechai_vig", @class = "form-control datepicker", @onkeyup = "borrar(this);" } })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FECHAI_VIG, "De", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "active" })                        
</div>
```

And in the script

```
<script>
    var elemth = document.querySelector('#fechai_vig');
    var optionsth = { 
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        i18n: {
            clear: 'Limpiar',
            today: 'Hoy',
            done: 'Seleccionar',
            previousMonth: '‹',
            nextMonth: '›',
            months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
            weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
            weekdaysAbbrev: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S']
        }
    };
    var instanceth = M.Datepicker.init(elemth, optionsth);  
</script>
```